HAS_DBACCESS in SQL Azure not working from master
When I run the following query against master in an on prem or managed instance, I get a 1 or 0 result.
select HAS_DBACCESS(N'MyRep')

However, when run against SQL Azure against master I get NULL.
If I switch the query execution to run against MyRep in SQL Azure, then I get the 1 returned as I expect, but that's a chicken and egg scenario.
Is there a way to ask an azure server when connected to master if a user has access to a database without first attempting to connect to the database? Or am I missing some basic security principle?
I asked copilot this question and it gave me some SQL to join on database principals and permissions, and it didn't work (no surprise).

Azure SQL Databases are all contained databases, so each database should, really, be treated like it's its own unique environment. Cross database "stuff" doesn't work because of these, and the databases themselves can actually all be hosted in different locations, even though you are connecting to a single "instance" (it's not actually an instance). Generally, as a result, people connect with database scoped credentials, not logins. As a result, not things like trying to work out what databases someone has access to from master doesn't work, because that's not how it's designed.

@ThomA thanks. It's odd though that if that was the case, why can I still see MyRep in select * from master.sys.databases

I assume you are using a sysadmin LOGIN. As I stated, most connections won't be made as a sysadmin, but a database-scoped USER.

HAS_DBACCESS is not supported on Azure SQL Database (DTU-model, vCore-model, Serverless, Hyperscale) based on Microsoft documentation. Of all PaaS database offerings, it is only supported on Azure SQL Managed Instance that is the Azure SQL flavor that most represent a traditional SQL Server instance.
You can query the sys.database_principals and sys.database_permissions views to check if a user has access to a database.
SELECT 
DB_NAME() as DatabaseName,
dp.name AS UserName,
dp.type_desc AS UserType,
dp.create_date,
dp.modify_date,
p.permission_name,
p.state_desc AS PermissionState
FROM 
sys.database_principals AS dp
LEFT JOIN 
sys.database_permissions AS p
ON 
dp.principal_id = p.grantee_principal_id
WHERE 
dp.name = 'your_user_name';


Thanks for your reply, I think you're missing a join or 'where' to the databases table to discover the name/id of the database the user has permissions for?

I added the Database Name on the output of the query. However, these are Dynamic Management Views (sys.database...) that only exist within each database. So you know to what database you are connected when you run the query to know if a user has access to the database you are connected.

These DMVs bring information for one database only, the database you are connected.
